# how to upload google drive file from shared URL to AWS s3 in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, google-drive-api, laravel-5

I would like to ask is there a way to upload google drive file to AWS S3 in Laravel?

> For example, I have this URL for the file from google drive.
>   https://drive.google.com/file/d/1egGhrx1nMUNOgZ8QALMMB9cOOodPKfBs/view?usp=sharing
>   Want to move it to AWS S3 without downloading in the directory?
>
> GOOGLE
>    DRIVE FILE --- Direct Upload To----> AWS S3

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried small file from Google drive to S3 in this way and that work but for large file, it is not saving.
Storage::disk('s3')->put('kkkkkk', file_get_contents('https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1yRt-ZWZ4OdrD33XHaYLiftBx796IujAL'), 'public');
This is working, large file failed. :( Large file save as HTML on live due to virus scan.